# Can "mess around" be used in this context?

Tags: phrases, idiomatic-language

***So I stepped out on my porch and yelled at him to get the (swear word) off my lawn. At first he thought I was joking, but then he ran. He could tell I wasn't messing around.***

Is "wasn't messing around" natural in this context to mean that he could tell that I was dead serious?

What else could be said to mean that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's natural and suitable in the colloquialism given that the preceding sentence uses a wear word.

You could use something like "I wasn't kidding" but it may be tautological given the "joking" in the previous sentence.